# How can I highlight custom datatypes in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Where I work we use a lot of our own custom data types. The c++ that emacs recognizes, notices many of the custom datatypes from the STL such as string, vector, etc. This means that in my editor if i declare a function like so:

```
string getString() const {
    return str;
}
```

The return value will be highlighted green and due to this the function name will in blue. Now if I decide to use a custom string this messes everything up. So now my cpp files are mostly in white because we don't use the normal stl classes here. How can I program my emacs editor to recognize that when I mean 'String', color it the same way you would as 'string'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `font-lock-add-keywords`. Here's an example:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'cc-mode
  '(("String" . font-lock-type-face)
    ("str" . font-lock-type-face)))
```

It adds a list of regular expression/font lock pairs.

There's much more to be read on the topic of [adding-keywords](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords).
In particular, [ctypes.el](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ctypes.el) might be of interest to you.

Comment: one thing though.. i've just noticed that this just highlights the keywords. It doesn't tell emacs that these words should be recognized as c++ keywords. So due to this the function names are still white and the keyword 'String' will get highlighted anywhere even if its part of a function name (eg. GetString )

Comment: You should use a more precise regular expression - something like ("\\s+(String)\\s*" 1 font-lock-type-face). That would match String only if prefixed by tabs or spaces and if it's followed by optional whitespace.